# Text-DIV width same as the following responsive Datatable

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

i have a responsive Datatable embedded in a bootstrap card design. If I typing more text in the table the table and so on the card gets wider.

Now I want a div with multiple lines text in it above this Datatable.

But i dont know i can say "be as wide as the following div". I tried already width auto or 100% but this makes it fullscreen.

I set the max-width=100% but this maxs the div fullscreensize

Comment: try adding your code to get an answer even if your code isn't complete. And better, use HTML, CSS, javascript executable code snippet.

Comment: See [mre] for more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've not added a code snippet, I'm going based on assumptions here,
You want a div with text in it, and you want another div with the database in it, and you want both of those div(s) to take same width.

Just put both of those div(s) inside one container div

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="text"></div>
    <div class="database"></div>
</div>
```

put `width: 100%` on all three of them (considering the container div is already inside a bunch of other nested div(s))

```
.container{
    width:100%;
}
.text{
    width:100%;
}
.database{
    width:100%;
}
```

But again, this answer *MIGHT* be wrong considering I answered it based on what I assumed your question is, just keep in mind to attach code snippets and other references for us to answer your question accordingly.

Comment: Hi, sorry i forgotten to add an example code, your example fits.

Comment: But still there is the problem, when the text is wider than the table, the container gets wider and not the text gets broken into more lines

Comment: Could you write some of your code in a CodePen and share the link to me here? I'll take a look and could probably help you out.